# Is there a way to detect screen resolution in flex 4?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, adobe, resolution, detect

I want to make an application with an image that only bounces to the users screen resolution. How can I go by detecting the users screen resolution in flex 4? (If you can that is.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From http://www.sapethemape.com/2009/01/detecting-screen-resolution-in-flexair/, it looks like you can use `Capabilities.screenResolutionX` and `Capabilities.screenResolutionY`.

**Example:**

```
private function CapabilitiesMax():void
{
    width = Capabilities.screenResolutionX;
    height = Capabilities.screenResolutionY;
    stage.nativeWindow.x = 0;
    stage.nativeWindow.y = 0;
}
```

Comment: Yep. Npte that you will only get valeus from the main monitor.

Comment: You can access other monitors resolution if you target AIR

Comment: For Mobile development: Mind that will report the computer screen resolution when using the device emulator, not the emulated device's screen resolution.

Answer (score 3):

To find the resolution of multiple monitors, you can loop through the Screen.screens array and then get the bounding rectangle of each monitor screen. Typically AIR counts from left to right (0 index the right most monitor) but I haven't tested this on every monitor configuration.

```
import flash.display.Screen;

for(var i:int = 0; i < Screen.screens.length; i++)
{
    var x = Screen.screens[i].bounds.left;
    var y = 0;
    var width = Screen.screens[i].bounds.width;
    var height = Screen.screens[i].bounds.height;
}
```